# Trying to setup gmail on an ipad using a g-suite legacy domain. Get an error: "g suite access is disabled on this device"

Tags: ipad, gmail

I have an account in a g-suite legacy domain and I'm trying to setup an iPad (Legacy g-suite domains are from back when they were free and lack some features).

I've gone through the process, but gmail says: "gsuite access for xxx@yyy.org is disabled on this device."

According to Google help, I need to enable IOS Sync in IOS settings in Device Management in my g-suite admin page.   However, this feature is not available to Legacy g-suite users.

Does this mean I need to return my iPad?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went back and forth in a Google support forum and found the answer.

The documentation (perhaps wrongly), pointed me at the "IOS settings" under Domain Management -> Device Management as the place to fix this.  The problem is that Legacy Domains do not have this feature and it's greyed out.

However, If you go to Device Management -> Setup -> Sync on Mobile, there's another feature called "IOS Sync".  Turning this on was enough to solve my problem.

iPad is now working perfectly with Gmail and Google Docs.